# How to open an ajax pdf callback on new tab or force download?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdf

I'm trying to make a simple "service order" system for a client.

First the client fills a form with multimple inputs, then the data is send using ajax to a PHP file that generates a PDF file.

I'm using html2pdf php library https://html2pdf.fr/en/home, and this is the headers' response i get from every ajax request i make:

```
Cache-Control   no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
connection  close
content-description File Transfer
content-disposition attachment; filename="orden-28012018-005747.pdf"
content-transfer-encoding   binary
content-type    application/pdf
date    Sun, 28 Jan 2018 06:57:47 GMT
Expires 0
last-modified   Sun, 28 Jan 2018 06:57:47 GMT
Pragma  no-cache
server  Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.24
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
x-powered-by    PHP/5.6.24
```

and  i can't get to show the pdf or something, i want to either open it on new tab or force a download of the file.

Can you please help me out?.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using ajax instead of a form?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax and we can close this topic.